# Will bundle path change when updated with a new version?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, version-control, nsbundle

If I update my iPhone/iPad application with the new version (1.1) will the bundle path change?

For example, my bundle path for 1.0 is `/var/mobile/Applications/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/Library/Caches/xxx`. If I update my application with a new version (for example, 1.1) will this path change or not?

Comment: @satheeshwaran: no you are not correct. this "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx" will change after update. So use relative paths

Comment: You always have to refer the documents directory by using NSSearchForDirectoriesInDomains method. If you do that even if the part you say is going to change, you will still be referring to the same path.

Answer (score 0):

you should not rely on absolute path! Is not a good idea... you should use the NSBundle methods to get the path of a file into the bundle, and to get your application home directory use the relative functions

this to get your home directory

```
NSHomeDirectory()
```

and after you can append the relative path like

```
[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Caches/xxx"]
```

Comment: Yes you are right,But i need to know that Path will change or not.

Comment: @Madhu It doesn't matter. Even if it didn't, you should assume it might, and use the method described in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you directly access to cache directory by using this code line

```
[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] copy]
```

this line of code return you path as string

if you want anything else then please comment